# How to migrate Alibaba Cloud ECS instance to Azure VM？

Tags: azure, azure-vm, alibaba-cloud

I am running a WordPress website with Linux (CentOS 7) instance on Alibaba Cloud. For some reason, I need to migrate the website to Azure. Can I just export the snapshot from alibaba cloud and import it to Azure and create VM base on it? Or is there any tool I can use to do this?

Comment: I have two ECS instances, one for web host and another for mysql.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to administration of an application, not a specific programming problem.